# Ubuntu 16.04 - Count Folder File Limit

Tags: 16.04, disk

[image][image]i write a code, which creates and stores text-files in my hard disk(fat32). I create 9361 files. So, if I add to the Folder a new txt file i became the error: **No space left on the disk**

Is there any limitation? If yes, how can I solve this problem? I must add files to the Folder ( < 16k )

thanks a lot

Comment: Some of the limitation of Fat32 : 2^28 total files, 65534 files per directory, 4Gio max files size - You may change the filesystem type

Comment: But my file size per directory is smaller than 65534 and the size <4Gio.. I have only ~9000 text Files and ~9000 Images..

Comment: Please edit your question and copy/paste the output of this `lsblk -fm /dev/sda`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. I change the format type from fat32 to ntfs.